# C# - Sort File.ReadLines IEnumerable without Memory Overhead?

Tags: c#

Is this possible?

I have the following code to reduce the total amount of memory usage:

```
File.WriteAllLines(
    Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(file[0]), "(Sort A-Z) " + Path.GetFileName(file[0])),
    File.ReadLines(file[0]).OrderBy(s=>s)
);
```

(file[0] is the input file path).

This reduces usage from ForEach's e.t.c reducing CPU usage aswell as memory usage (barely).
Its also faster than using a Foreach.
The issue however, is the .OrderBy(s=>s) causes it to load the entire thing into memory. Its not as bad as normally loading it into memory, but it still rises quite a bit of memory. (Im using a 80mb file).

Is there some way to order the IEnumerable/Order by A->Z when saving to a file without using much memory?

I know it sounds vague and unsure what im looking for, because I dont know myself.

Running with .OrderBy(s=>s) on a 2.7 million line file:
https://i.imgur.com/rUyDeFJ.gifv

Running WITHOUT .OrderBy(s=>s) on a 2.7 million line file:
https://i.imgur.com/Ejbnuty.gifv
(You can see it finish)

Comment: It would be much slower.  If you do not use memory you need some temporary storage for doing the sort so you would need to use a temp file to perform the sort.  Reading and Writing to a file is much slower than using memory.  The other choice would be to use a database and store the data in the database and let the database perform the sort.

Comment: @jdweng None of that makes any sense. If I were to use temporary storage, it would be loaded into memory, which is exactly what im doing right now and what im not looking to do.

Comment: "the .OrderBy(s=>s) causes it to load the entire thing into memory" What makes you think that? `File.ReadLines`reads a file in a non-blocking way, so that you can perform LINQ operations on it before consuming it completely. It has to, at some point, read the entire file, otherwise you couldn't write it in `WriteAllLines`

Comment: File.ReadLines along with File.WriteAllLines doesnt actually store anything in memory (not overhead memory atleast) so it stays a full straight line in memory while writing. In my code, removing the .OrderBy() has it be straight, meaning .OrderBy() will sort it in a temporary array or something, which adds each one of 2.7million lines into memory, and then sends it back, and then WriteAllLines writes it to the file.

Comment: @Camilo But how does that interact with `OrderBy()`?

Comment: When you swap two number you use temp = a, a = b, b = temp.  You can do same with using files to sort data which will not use memory.  The algorithm is extremely slow, but was used years ago before we had cheap huge memory.

Comment: I showed gif's explaining and showing that the .OrderBy is affecting memory.

Comment: How would the sorting work without loading everything into memory, though? You have to have the entire input data to be able to sort

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Thats true I suppose :/

Comment: I concur with previous comments - you can't use plain sort without loading everything into memory. However there are techniques that will use an intermediate file (temp storage referred earlier) for sorting - that will save you on memory usage, but will take up HDD space and be much more slower. And I'm not aware of any inbuilt C# features that will do that for you, so you'll have to come up with the algorithm yourslf.

Comment: Here are some reference links: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort  http://www.algosome.com/articles/how-to-sort-large-file.html

Comment: Maybe you could use command line "sort" [(e.g. super user Q&A)](https://superuser.com/questions/81622/sort-utility-on-the-command-line). As shown in the [documentation](https://ss64.com/nt/sort.html) you can also limit the memory usage using `/M`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is necessary for .OrderBy to load the entire contents into memory. It would be impossible for it to work any other way.

OrderBy receives an IEnumerable. Therefore it receives items on at a time. However, consider the scenario where the very last row needs to be sorted before the very first row. This could only be achieved if the last row and first row were both in memory at the same time. Consider the scenario where the entire input were already sorted in the reverse order. Hopefully these examples show why it is necessary for OrderBy to load the entire contents into memory.

Algorithms exist to partition data sets into individual partitions, on disk, then merge those partitions. However, they are beyond the scope of the Linq OrderBy function.

Internally OrderBy reads everything into a buffer array then performs a quicksort over it. If you're feeling brave, refer to the reference source:
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,2530
(It's scattered throughout this file, but lines 2534-2542 best illustrate this)

Comment: Nice! Good reference link!